# HttpHandler not firing from body of .aspx page

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, httphandler

I have a http handler that is called from a .aspx page in the form 1x1 pixel image. The handler has an extension of .jpg set up in the web.config. On all browsers apart from IE the http handler is called successfully from the body of the page when it loads.

However in IE the httphandler is not called.

If I call the http handler by entering the url in to the address bar in IE it works perfectly.

Any idea why it might not work in the body of the page?

Comment: How are you calling it from a page?

Comment: eg. <img src="http://<path>/0104924934404624104049.jpg" height="1" width="1" />

Comment: Have you tried to see if a request is being made via something like Fiddler?

Comment: Perhaps IE requires the response to have a relevant Content-Type header when making a request for an `<img/>`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IE may have it cached the image. If the filename of the .jpg isn't changing, I'd try to add a random query string to the end of it.

`http://<path>/0104924934404624104049.jpg?random=<unix timestamp>`